scrollIntoView not working when the component is out of focus, on chromium based browsers
I'm building a react single page app and have noticed that the scrollIntoView function does not work on chrome based browsers (tested on edge&chrome) when the component is out of focus.
I have a long async operation that involves waiting on a server response. When that response arrives, some elements are being created and the page should scroll them into view. Losing focus causes the scrolling operation to fail.
useEffect(() => {
    const onFocus = () => {
      console.log('gained focus')
    }

    const onBlur = () => {
      console.log('lost focus: ', currentStage)
    }

    window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus)
    window.addEventListener('blur', onBlur)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('focus', onFocus)
      window.removeEventListener('blur', onBlur)
    }
  }, [])

I use this for debugging purposes ^
and this is the actual scroll logic:
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    attemptScroll()

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(scrollEndTimer.current)
    }
  }, [currentStage, activeStages])

(the stage changes upon server response)
const attemptScroll = () => {
    console.log(`current stage: ${currentStage.name}`)

    if (!scrollerRef.current) return

    const stageElement = document.getElementById(currentStage?.name)
    if (!stageElement) {
      console.error(`Stage ${currentStage?.name} was not found in the DOM`)
      console.error(currentStage)
      return
    }

    console.log('scrolling to element:', stageElement.current)
    setScrolling(true)
    stageElement.focus()
    stageElement.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start',
      inline: 'start'
    })

    const checkScrollCompletion = callback => {
      clearTimeout(scrollEndTimer.current)
      const lastScrollLeft = scrollerRef.current.scrollLeft

      scrollEndTimer.current = setTimeout(() => {
        const currentScrollLeft = scrollerRef.current.scrollLeft
        if (currentScrollLeft === lastScrollLeft) {
          callback()
        } else {
          checkScrollCompletion(callback)
        }
      }, 100)
    }

    setScrolling(false)
  }

Just to make is super clear:

server responds
currentStage is updated
use layout effect is called
attemptScroll() is called
all code inside attemptScroll executes, except for scrollIntoView

Even the 'scrolling to element' log statement is being written, with the correct element. Everything works as intended, except for the scroll.
I could technically work around this by making the page attempt scrolling when the component returns to focus, but even after if I ignore the UX hit, I noticed the it loses focus on mobile even when the browser is still open on the screen, so just randomly tapping the screen until something happens is a no go.
Does anybody know why and how can I fix this?
Thanks
